# Git log of tags solely, in a given range

Tags: git, git-log, git-tag

I wish to do what `git log --no-walk --tags --decorate=short` does, but I also want to check for tags in a given range soley (commit range), not just all the tags.

Comment: What kind of range?  by date?  by starting and ending commit/tag ids? something else?

Comment: @Wolf commit/tag ids. Will update the question with that.

Comment: What exactly is a "tag range"?  If the tags are `fred`, `barney`, `betty`, and `wilma`, which ones are in which range?  (More usefully, you may want `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/tags`, which you can then pipe into a program to do your tag selection.  Feed the selected tags as additional arguments to `git log --no-walk --decorate=short`.)

Comment: @torek a tag is a name for a commit, so when talking about a tag I'm solely referring to the ref for that commit and you can understand it as a commit ref.

Comment: Ah, so you may want to choose only tags that match a commit that is in something like `X..Y` aka `Y ^X`.  You'll need to write code for this, using `git for-each-ref` and `git rev-list`.  While rev-list itself *can* do union operations, it cannot do intersections.)

Comment: @torek I've removed "tag range" from the question to avoid this interpretation.

Comment: @torek =/ I was expecting something just as simple as a command like the one I use for all the tags...

Comment: @torek for me this would offer a nice changelog functionality since on tagged commits (which are merge commits of pulls) lies docs of what has been added on point releases.

Comment: Ah, if all your tags are always merges, there's another trick we can use, `--merges`.  We do still have the set intersection issue (see answer below), but you might not even need to check for tags this way: just use `rev-list` to get all such merges, then look to see if there are attached changelog docs in those commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: as [jthill noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490767/git-log-of-tags-solely-in-a-given-range/38493251?noredirect=1#comment64387580_38493251), `git rev-list` (and hence `git log`) has `--simplify-by-decoration`, which *discards* commits that do not have a (branch or) tag-name pointing to them:

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --decorate=short X..Y
```

may do just what you want.  Unfortunately, testing shows that it also keeps commits that have a branch-name pointing to them.  [The documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) is not 100% clear on this:

> `--simplify-by-decoration`
>    Commits that are referred by some branch or tag are selected.

but then later:

> The `--simplify-by-decoration` option allows you to view only the big
>    picture of the topology of the history, by omitting commits that are
>    not referenced by tags. ...

Original answer below line (it should work).

---

OK, it sounds like you want to combine the effects of something like `X..Y` with "select only commits that have a tag pointing to them".

There are two main Git commands for doing this kind of operation:

- [`git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html), which lets you work with reference names—any name from anywhere within the `refs/` name-space; tags are in `refs/tags/`.
- [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html), which is actually kind of the same command as `git log` except that instead of showing commit messages by default, it shows hashes by default.  (There are other minor differences, but they are so similar that both `git log` and `git rev-list` are built from one source file.)

The main problem you have here is that while `git log` / `git rev-list` easily let you restrict which commit(s) are selected, with `Y ^X` or `X..Y` for one example, or with `--no-walk --tags[=pattern]` for another, they're not very good at set intersection operations.  They can directly do limited union style operations, e.g., `git rev-list --no-walk --tags=foo\* --tags=bar\* --branches=baz\*` would print the ID of every commit tagged with a name that matches `foo*` or `bar*`, or is pointed-to by a branch name matching `baz*`.

(The `rev-list` command *can* do full, arbitrary set union operations using pipes and `--stdin`, but not intersections.  This is one area where Mercurial's syntax beats Git's.  Of course Mercurial has the advantage of having all of Python to fall back onto, internally.)

What you want, though, is the intersection of two sets:

- set 1: your range selection, probably something like `X..Y` or `--since=date1 --until=date2`
- set 2: every commit pointed-to by (some or all) tags

Computing this set intersection requires some code.  On a Unix-like system we have all the tools we need: Git itself, and `comm`, which can do the set intersection.  The `comm` utility needs its input to be sorted so we'll pipe each set through `sort` here.  So we just need a short (7 line) script.

We start with the usual temp file boilerplate, e.g.:

```
tf1=$(mktemp) || die "can't make first temp file"
trap "rm -f $tf1" 0 1 2 3 15
tf2=$(mktemp) || die "can't make second temp file"
trap "rm -f $tf1 $tf2" 0 1 2 3 15
```

Now we get set 1 using `git rev-list`:

```
git rev-list <specifiers> | sort > $tf1
```

Then we get set 2, using `git for-each-ref`.  Assuming we want annotated tags to resolve to their objects (usually a commit, but maybe another annotated tag, but if it's another annotated tag we'll let *that* tag resolve on its own), we get set 2 with:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(object)' refs/tags | sort > $tf2
```

Note that this is `%(object)`, not `%(objectname)`; the latter would only get us the ID of the annotated tag object.

Finally, we want only commit IDs that are in *both* temp files, i.e., we want `comm -12` which suppresses all but column 3 (lines that are in both files):

```
comm -12 $tf1 $tf2
```

The output of this script is the set of commits to show (in an order determined by sorting their commit hashes, so we'll rely on `git log` to fix the sort order).  Now we just use your original `git log` command, but run it on the selected commits:

```
git log --no-walk --decorate=short --date-order $(script)
```

(this is all untested of course).

If `git rev-list` had a `--stdin-intersect` option we could do all this within Git and the shell:

```
git log --no-walk --decorate=short $( \
    git for-each-ref --format='%(object)' refs/tags | \
    git rev-list --stdin-intersect X..Y \
)
```

but it doesn't, hence the need for the little script.

Comment: There's also `git log --simplify-by-decoration X..Y`

Comment: @jthill ah no, it didn't work exactly well. I'm getting commits that are not tagged being listed.

Comment: I'm not sure what pattern the log is following at all (with jthill command), it's just showing a handful of commits that include the tagged ones, but also there are some other listed, with multiple heads or name of other branches.

Comment: Ah yeah, it's logging every branch commit head and tags.